# How to Web API get/post DTO with image?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How to design a WebAPI controller and other configurations to transfer the below DTO over the wire?

```
public class DTOTestImage
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageDetails { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

and MS SQL 2008R2 back end
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TestImage]
(
    ImageNAME NVARCHAR(80) DEFAULT(''),
    ImageDetails NVARCHAR(80) DEFAULT(''),
    [Image] VARBINARY(MAX) ,
    [RECID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) 
    PRIMARY KEY (ImageNAME)
)

Comment: -1 You don't seem to have taken the time to research the question. What have you tried yourself? This should be pretty easy to do. However SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: there are many like the one below

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/returning-images-from-asp.net-web-api.htm but Could not find one like our?

Comment: consider hiring a consultant then. The tutorial you reference should be easily adapted.

Comment: Aron, Would you like to take the job?

Answer (score 0):

quite easy. simply transfer bytes as it is from db along with the DTO, and use a bytes to imagesource converter to bind mvvm to the image control. that's it.